# z-index not bringing element to top

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is a picture of a downwards arrow and when the user clicks it, it should decrement a number, however I cannot get the click to fire because it seems to be below another element.

To explain the html, it is two bootstrap grid system rows, but the downwards arrow image is in the top row, however, it is dropped down low, so the bottom row goes over top of it.

image:
[image]

Here is the css of the downwards arrow (it has a high z-index):

```
#down-arrow-icon {
  background: url("../../assets/images/home_page/down-arrow.svg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4" align="center" style="height: 200px;display: flex;align-items: center;margin-top:-60px;">
  <div style="margin-right:20px;">
      <div id="up-arrow-icon" data-bind="click: incrementDistance"></div>
      <label data-bind="text: numberDistance" style="border:1px solid #fff; 
                border-radius: 50px; 
                width:100px; 
                height: 100px;
                font-weight:100;
                line-height:96px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-size: 44px;">11</label>
      <div id="down-arrow-icon" data-bind="click: decrementDistance"></div>
  </div>
    <div id="search-button" class="form-group" style="float:right;">
        <label id="distance-type">KILOMETERS</label>
        <div class="form-control-icon" id="switch-icon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4" align="center" style="margin-top: -73px;">
                <h1 id="search-filter-heading" class="heading form-group">OF
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
```

How do I make the downwards arrow be on top so that it registers the clicks?

Comment: Position must be applied for zindex to work

Comment: `z-index` only works in positioned elements, AKA `position` different value of `static`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`z-index` will work only for positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).**

Thus, add `position:relative/absolute/fixed` to your CSS.

ie, your new CSS would be like

```
#down-arrow-icon {
  background: url("../../assets/images/home_page/down-arrow.svg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please apply position: relative for z-index to work

```
#down-arrow-icon {
  background: url("../../assets/images/home_page/down-arrow.svg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative
  z-index: 9999;
}
```